# Will connecting USB controllers to a hub with extension cables cause interference, signal loss or even input lag?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-hub

I'd like to connect 3 devices to a USB hub. The USB hub is then connected to my PC with an extension cable.

Each device would need an extension cable of approx. 1m, which is then connected to the hub. The hub then has a 1-2m extension cable leading to the PC.

Since these 3 devices are medium to high-end controllers, I was wondering what kind of interference or signal loss or even input lag I might expect at these ranges. My gut says it will be just fine, but I'd rather ask someone more experienced than me.

Comment: I didn't feel like writing an answer, given that there already is a good one. I just wanted to point out that USB is a digital signal cable, so the latency is so small, its neglectable. You're talking about maybe a 1 nanosecond delay over 10 meters of cable.

Comment: USB 2.0 spec lists a maximum length of 5m.  This should be per leg, so 5m from controller to hub, 5m from hub to computer.  If your cables are of decent quality, a 1m extension should not have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are more likely to find that you have problems with the power that each port is designed to 'hand out'.

If you go to your control panel > system > Device Manager > expand universal serial bus controllers and double click on your Generic USB Hubs one by one looking at the second tab on the top.

You will see what power the external hub is drawing and how much is available at the top if its over the amount available you will face some issues.

Apart from that I have a keyboard, mouse and speakers running on an external hub and extension of about 3m and I have no issues whatsoever and its got enough power and the speakers are externally powered so its all good.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I will do some testing with the hub. Maybe I can get one with external power supply if it needs more than the port is giving out.